# A proper way to commit "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives" project to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I created a **Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives** project in **Eclipse** to manage the dependencies. But when I wanted to commit this project to **SVN**, it listed many `.class` files on the commit page.

[image]

Is it possible to commit these dependencies as **JAR** files?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer:
Just **uncheck** the `Unzip the JAR archives into the project` option when `New` the project. Then the dependency will ship as **JAR** files.

[image]